# Remove characters after the last occurrence of a specific character

Tags: r, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
exampleList <- c("rs40535:1745233:G:A_AGGG","rs41111:1733320:GAC:AAC_TTTTTTG", "exm2344379:1724237:A:T_A", "exm-rs234380:1890910:A:G_A", "rs423444419_T","psy_rs73453432_TCCC","22:1701234072:C:T_C","9:4534345:rs2342342_G","chr10_rs7287862_C","psy_rs7291672_A")
```

I wish to remove everything after the last underscore ( _ ) so my result looks something like this:

```
[1] "rs40535:1745233:G:A"      "rs41111:1733320:GAC:AAC"  "exm2344379:1724237:A:T"   "exm-rs234380:1890910:A:G"   "rs423444419"              "psy_rs73453432"           "22:1701234072:C:T"        "9:4534345:rs2342342"     "chr10_rs7287862"          "psy_rs7291672"
```

I've tried the following, but this removes everything after the first _.

```
gsub("\\_.*$","",exampleList)
```

I recognize there are similar posts but none I could find in R.

Comment: look into `qdapRegex`, particularly `rm_between`

Comment: Alternative to the existing answer: [`sub("^(.*)_.*", "\\1", exampleList)`](https://tio.run/##TZDBigIxDIbvPsUwpxlZpUlaOw17KT30ssc5isWVAQUFaRXcp59NZz1sKRTy/fkSmud5eh1v9@v0dSmP5nPTnLo2F60MGQarDRJxZJ98jLH9qAjkCCIiVBx9YO9DGpcjiaadXjckrck6SaFGsux5TP7NNrkIpkExDE45UELjHxV57dQaXBpl2L38pFwsaSMNmMYQglQRxatAksoiB1HXquMlpQ0v/npTXfh0zqCqBQc77HDJvr3oYGdRRverVXl@d@2h2677tF3XXfZ7kOff3/Tz/As) [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EtHRS9/1) (also useful to remove part after any last occurrence consisting of more than just one character)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
outcome <- sub("_[^_]+$", "", exampleList)
```